# Linking Flights in a Schedule with R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a `tibble` of flights for a given airline schedule that I am trying to 'link' together. The data follows the IATA SSIM format, or more explicitly contains the current flight 'key' and the following flight 'key'. I am trying to 'link' these flights to determine the number of aircraft in that schedule. For example, if a schedule looks like:

```
flight123 -> flight456 -> flight789 -> end
flight987 -> flight654 -> flight321 -> end
```

This would require two (2) aircraft to fly.
I have been able to accomplish this using `which()`, `match()`, or `filter()`, but I am having issues with the speed. My `tibble` has over 200,000 rows so this is taking more than 8 minutes to return. I would like this to return in less than a minute, if possible. Example below:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% mutate(nextIndex = purrr::map(nextKey, function(id){match(x = id, table = dat$key)}))
```

Could `group_by()` or `nest()` help to improve speed? Using a `for()` loop took an absurd amount of time...

Here is a slice of the data... unfortunately, the IATA industry standard format does not include much data as the format is ancient. The key is defined as `{FlightNumber}/{DepartureDate}{Origin}`. Tail numbers are not assigned and therefore not available.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   key             nextKey        
   <glue>          <glue>         
 1 3845/13Apr19GGG 3876/13Apr19DFW
 2 246/29Apr19CLT  123/29Apr19PBI  
 3 2561/24Apr19PHX 2604/24Apr19BOS
 4 2101/01Apr19DCA 1660/01Apr19DFW
 5 3443/21Apr19BTR 3703/21Apr19DFW
 6 2772/07Apr19JFK 1810/07Apr19AUS
 7 784/21Apr19BWI  NA 
 8 5199/25Apr19PHL 5090/25Apr19HVN
 9 375/14Apr19JAX  2360/14Apr19DFW
10 5517/30Apr19YYZ 5301/30Apr19DCA
```

Ideally, I would like the final result to be `grouped` or `nested` by each individual line of flying (aircraft).

Comment: can you output a sample of your data? My guess is pivoting the data is what needs to happen. Is each row a flight? Is the key the tail # or is there a column that has the next flt # + Origin.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @RyanJohn I have updated the post with sample data. Tail numbers are not assigned, therefore not available. Current origin and next origin city are available.

Comment: How do you know where the flight ends? Row 1 goes from GGG -> DFW -> ? end?

Comment: @RyanJohn if the `nextKey` field is `NA` then there is no following flight

Comment: Sounds like some form of pivotting might help out a lot, but I'm having a hard time undestanding how the data's structured.

Comment: I think we need the data a step before the glue step. I dont believe you've described how one line of flying ends. The flight leaving DFW could land after midnight in CLT.